# Images in Row Staggered

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display multiple links with rollover images in a row and it is staggering the images.  I have tried adding clear:left; to the css code and it just makes the images stack on top of each other.  Can someone please help me figure out how I can have these link images display in a row without staggering?  Thank you!!

HTML:

```css
#iconwrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.CasinoLink {
  display: inline;
  width: 279px;
  height: 237px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/300/300');
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
.CasinoLink:hover {
  background-position: -279px 0;
}
.CorpLink {
  display: inline;
  width: 279px;
  height: 237px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/300/300');
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 5px 0 5px;
}
.CorpLink:hover {
  background-position: -279px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="iconwrap">
  <a class="CasinoLink" href=""></a>
  <a class="CorpLink" href=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by staggered, one on top of each other?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. As you can see by the snippet in the question, what you 've posted doesn't show us anything.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

CSS

```
.image-outer-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.image-outer-wrapper:before,
.image-outer-wrapper:after { content: " "; display: table;}
.image-outer-wrapper:after {clear: both;}

  .image-outer-wrapper .image-wrapper {
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 279px;
    height: 237px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

  .image-outer-wrapper .image-wrapper.CasinoLink {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/279x237');
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  .image-outer-wrapper .image-wrapper.CorpLink {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/279x237');
    background-position: 0 0;
  }

  .image-outer-wrapper .image-wrapper:hover {
    background-position: -279px 0;
  }
```

HTML

```
  <div class="image-outer-wrapper">
    <div class="image-wrapper CasinoLink"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper CorpLink"></div>
  </div>
```

see here for EG: http://codepen.io/simondavies/pen/VaRBMo